# Searching for an input_from_user word in a set of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Guys I was trying to search for a word that will be entered by the user in a list of files in a folder and so far I have this code :

```
import os

folderpath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Documents"
word = input("Choose a word : ")

for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folderpath, topdown=True):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            info = f.readlines()
            for line in info:
                if word in line:
                    print( filename + ":" + "[1]" )
                else:
                    print(filename + "[0]")
```

the output is the name of each file 10 times then 1,0,1,0... respectively(ex: Doc1[1] , Doc1[0] , Doc1[1]....). It looks like nothing is breaking the loop. Please any help

Comment: What do you want to happen when the word is found? This code will go through every file and every line and check whether the word is found in each one. If it is found on a line, it prints the file name with ": [1]" at the end, otherwise it prints the filename with [0]. There is nothing there that will break the loop, it will keep checking all the lines in the document, for every document,

Comment: I want this code to print the files just one 
if the word in the file print filename with [1]
else print filename with [0] 
it's a binary outcomes for each file either 1 or 0 and it`s not working it`s printing each file 10 times coz I`ve 10 files in the Path

Answer (score 1):

Your code is printing output for every line in every file, not just 10 times. I suspect your files are all 10 lines long if that is the case.

The following code just tests `str(info)` for the word, printing one match for each file:

```
import os

folderpath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Documents"
word = input("Choose a word : ")
for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folderpath, topdown=True):
    for filename in files:
        matched = 0
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            info = f.readlines()

        if word in str(info):
            matched = 1
        print("{}: [{}]".format(filename, matched))
```

If you wish your test to be case-insensitive, simply replace:

```
if word in str(info):
```

With:

```
if word.casefold() in str(info):
```

If you'd like to have an actual count of occurrences for each file in your output, you can do something like:

```
import os

folderpath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Documents"
word = input("Choose a word : ")
for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folderpath, topdown=True):
    for filename in files:
        count = 0
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            info = f.readlines()

            if word in str(info):
                for line in info:
                    if word in line:
                        count += 1

        print("{}: [{}]".format(filename, str(count)))
```

Take a look at the modified line 13 below, and you'll see each match along with the filename.

```
import os

folderpath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Documents"
word = input("Choose a word : ")

for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folderpath, topdown=True):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            info = f.readlines()
            for line in info:
                if word in line:
                    print( filename + ":" + "[1]:", line )
                else:
                    print(filename + "[0]")
```

Comment: first of all thank u alot , actually I do have 10 txt files in the path and I copied your code and pasted it, still not working 
I want when the user enter the word, the output will be Either filename + [1] if the word exists
or filename + [0] if the word does not exist

Comment: the output of your code is repeating filename sometimes when the word exists more than one time

Comment: That's what I assumed you were looking for. Every line that match. That's not your intent? Just the filename if it contains the word?

Comment: I modified the code that prints just `filename: [0]` or `filename: [1]` to simplify it slightly. Take a look now.

Comment: what I want is to print the filename once even if the word exists more than once, the number of the occurrence does not matter. If the word exists in the file print the filename once with [1] else print the filename once but with [0], consider it as a binary outcomes for a word occurrence in a file.
big thank to u :)

Comment: `if word in str(info):` tests for the presence of `word` in the `info` after coercing `info` from a `list` to a `string.` It's just one way to test all members of `info` at once rather than testing each member of `info`. `info` is a `list` of `list`s, each containing a line from the file.

Comment: just 1 more thing please, how can I lower case a whole folder that contains more than 1 txt file ?

Comment: I mean if I want the user search for his word but all in a lower case

Comment: Take a look at the answer now. I added case-insensitivity mention.

Comment: I meant to make all the files contents in the lower case! :) and I tried to add line= line,lower() and did not work

Comment: it worked know cos I added to your mention str(info).casefold() , thanks

Comment: You bet! Could you mark the answer as accepted? I mean, assuming it deserves it, of course. :) Thank you.

Comment: I did not understand i`m a new contributor in the site and I don`t know how to do that

Comment: You should see a little tick mark next to the question which you can click to say that Chris has answered your question. You can also press the up arrow to say that this is a good answer.